# React.js Mui Treeview: How to make on nodeselect not collapse

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make the Treeview not collapse every time I select a node. When node is selected it will render button depending on which node you have selected. Here is an example I made. https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-water-33fe7?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TreeItem` has a `disabled` prop which will not allow user to collapse the `TreeItem` on click. You can dynamically set the value of the `disabled` prop when you do not want it to collapse.

**For example :**

```
const [disabled, setDisabled] = useState(true);

<TreeItem nodeId="5" label="Five" disabled={disabled}>

// setDisabled(false); // Set to false when we want it to be collapsable.
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a way but not sure if this is the best way so basically I added all the ids that I want to be expanded all the time a.k.a every i.d in the data.

```
const DataTreeView = ({ treeItems }) => {
    return (
      <TreeView
        defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
        defaultExpanded={[
          "root",
          "root2",
          "Parent 1",
          "Parent 2",
          "Parent 3",
          "Parent 4",
          "1",
          "2",
          "3",
          "4"
        ]}
        onNodeSelect={action}
      >
        {getTreeItemsFromData(treeItems)}
      </TreeView>
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, I stumbled into this issue, as well as [not being able to set the focused node](https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/10236) (which for me, was a deal breaker).

The best answer I found was to use a [Mui Nested List](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-list/). Yeah, it takes a little work to make the indentation right, but it's a lot easier than dealing with TreeViews various oddities if you are really just wanting a hierarchical list.